# When to use "generally", "usually", or "normally"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

*Generally* speaking what are the *usually* accepted usage scenarios for the above mentioned words in a *normally* occurring English vernacular?

In short, what are the rules/guidelines for using *generally*, *usually* and *normally*?

Comment: Some people generally prefer usually to normally, while other generally prefer normally to usually.  Others normally prefer generally to usually while some normally prefer usually to generally.  Still others, though, usually prefer generally to normally and there are those that usually prefer normally to generally.  I generally say usually but sometimes normally. :-)

Comment: More often than not, _ordinarily_ will work, too.  For that matter, so will _more often than not_ – generally speaking.

Comment: @Jim: Wish I could give you a +1 as a new user I don't have access to the privilege just yet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are some subtle differences:

- Usually - X repeats over time, and some kind of variants happen more frequently than others. (time separation is implied)
- Generally - there are multiple instances of X, and there is more of some variant than others. (no time separation is implied)
- Normally - there are multiple instances of X, and there is more of the "standard" ones than the "weird" ones. (qualitative difference is implied).

Examples:

- *I usually shop at the grocery store on the corner.* (I do it repeatedly)
- *Generally, the prices at the shop on the corner are lower than down the street.* (most of the prices are lower, now)
- *Normally, the shop is open 6AM-10PM, except during World Cup, when the owner closes at 6PM.* (it's a special exception)

Answer (score 4):

They are generally similar, but as the basic meanings of those words show, *generally* seems to look at the broad picture and does not worry about minor details; *normally* focuses on the norm as opposed to exceptions; *usually* talks about frequency of events or describes a habit.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that *usually* and *generally* have a purely descriptive value: they mean that the phenomenon discussed happens with high frequency.

Although *normally* can have  that meaning too, it may also have a prescriptivist connotation: "this is the way it usually is and the way it should be".
In other words that's what *normal* people - a distinctly judgmental characterization!-  do or expect.

Answer (score 1):

I think "generally" has a more general use where "normally" and "usually" each imply that perhaps there is some hint to the contrary and that the speaker / writer is contrasting. However, I can see them all being used identically with little to no misunderstanding.

"I normally wouldn't do this, but..."
"Oh, it's usually a lot more crowded here."
"We generally eat lunch at noon."

Edit
I wasn't fully satisfied with my own answer, so I Googled and found [this](http://www.englishforums.com/English/UsuallyAndNormally/gpwww/post.htm).

> CalifJim: The example I came up with, before reading any other
>   responses, was similar to Clive's. People don't normally walk about
>   naked in public. You can substitute usually, but the emphasis on
>   "conformance to norms" is more important when you use normally.  For
>   inanimate objects, usually often seems more appropriate than normally.
>   Our piano usually goes out of tune once the weather turns cold. (It's
>   not really normal for a piano to be out of tune, so usually seems
>   better here, but here again, you can substitute normally.) CJ

Comment: Interesting take. So one needs to consider whether or not there is some uncertainty to the use of either of the words to mean in "most cases" or "most of the time" or "What is assumed to be the common occurrence".

Comment: (Speaking from personal experience: American native English speaker with most of my time in IN & FL with a strong influence from KY & TN) In everyday casaul usage when the speaker wants to use one of these words, each is probably as likely as the others to be used. I really like the distinction made by CalifJim on the other site, "normally" for "conformance to norms" and "usually" for something that happens frequently but would be outside of "normal", like the piano being out of tune.

Answer (score 0):

*Generally* something occurs generically enough in order to make a generalisation. It can be uncertain and conjecture.

*Usually* implies that something occurs often enough for it to be expected, but not assumed. In order for something to happen *usually* it must have happened in the past.

*Normally* states that the occurrence is the norm, not that any other outcome would be weird, but that the normal outcome is the most commonly occurring (or the mode). Use of *normally* implies that there is a norm, which *generally* and *usually* don't.

So:

> *Generally* when the apocalypse comes people will run for their lives.

As the apocalypse can only happen once *usually* doesn't work:

> *Usually* when the apocalypse comes people will run for their lives.

Also, as the apocalypse would not have a norm, so *normally* doesn't work either:

> *Normally* when the apocalypse comes people will run for their lives.

Or another example:

> *Generally* people will vote in the next general election.
>
> *Usually* they'll vote for the same party that they did last time.
>
> *Normally* people vote for one of the two largest parties.